# Unable to create labels for WebGL Feature Layer, esriGeometryPolyline is not supported

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcmap

I publish service from arcgis server and I am using it with the arcgis js 4.9. But one of Feature Layer I faced error :
[esri.views.2d.engine.webgl.WGLMeshFactory] ,
mapview-labeling:unsupported-geometry-type,
Unable to create labels for WebGL Feature Layer, esriGeometryPolyline is not supported" 
Now I can not show Label of layer. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the 4.9 [source code](https://js.arcgis.com/4.9/esri/views/2d/layers/features/Pipeline.js), the esriGeometryPolyline geometry type have "null" for value of possible label placements, and this will give you the error mentioned.

You could try to upgrade to 4.11, which has the "center-along" value available for esriGeometryPolyline.

I am currently researching an error where a user has gone from 4.4 to 4.11 and has gotten various display problems, which are probably related to some setting of labels in the web map and label placement for polylines.